# Any way to mass translate nodes?

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I tried using the entity_metadata_wrapper, but most of the fields can't get imported. Most of the time only the title is imported.

```
if (isset($result['node'])) {                                                 
  $exclude_fields = array(                                                    
    'nid',                                                                    
    'vid',                                                                    
    'is_new',                                                                 
    'language',                                                               
    'url',                                                                    
    'edit_url',                                                               
    'comment',                                                                
    'comment_new',                                                            
    'changed',                                                                
    'comment_count',                                                          
    'comment_count_new',                                                      
    'is_new',                                                                 
  );                                                                          

  $default_values = array(                                                    
    'language' => 'fr',                                                       
    'translate' => 1,                                                         
  );                                                                          

  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);                                        
  $entities = entity_load('node', $nids);                                     

  foreach ($entities as $entity) {                                            
    $entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);                       
    $keys = array_keys($entity->getPropertyInfo());                           
    $keys = array_diff($keys, $exclude_fields);                               

    $values = array();                                                        
    foreach ($keys as $key) {                                                 
    if ($entity->$key->value() !== null) {                                  
      $value= $entity->$key->value();                                       
      if(isset($value->summary)) {                                          
          unset($value->summary);                                             
        }                                                                     
        $values[$key] = $value;                                               
      }                                                                       
    }                                                                         
    $values += $default_values;                                               
    dpm($values);                                                             
    $return = entity_property_values_create_entity('node', $values)->save();                                                                                                                                    
    dpm($return);                                                             
  if($return === false) {                                                   
    dpm($values);                                                           
    }                                                                         
  }
```

If you any other approach, I'm willing to test it.